# MySQL Query Join to select unmatched rows from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql5

I have two tables as below.

---

```
user_id   |   username        |  first_name |   role_type
-----------------------------------------------------------
1         |   testuser1       |  testu1     |    student
2         |   testuser2       |  testu2     |    student
3         |   testuser3       |  testu3     |    student
4         |   testuser4       |  testu4     |    student
5         |   testuser5       |  testu5     |    student
6         |   testuser6       |  testu6     |    admin
7         |   testuser7       |  testu7     |    admin
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
user_id   |   username         |    approved_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1         |   testuser1        |  3B888F52-50BC-11E2-B08B-99E5B2CADDF7
2         |   testuser2        |  3B888F52-50BC-11E2-B08B-99E5B2CADDF7
3         |   testuser3        |  3B888F52-50BC-11E2-B08B-99E5B2CADDF7
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the query

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
WHERE users.username NOT IN(
     SELECT users_approval.username FROM users_approval 
     WHERE users_approval.approved_id = "3B888F52-50BC-11E2-B08B-99E5B2CADDF7"
) AND users.role_type = "student"
```

and got the result below

---

```
user_id   |   username        |  first_name |   role_type
-------------------------------------------------------------
4         |   testuser4       |  testu4     |    student
5         |   testuser5       |  testu5     |    student
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to use JOIN to fetch the same resultset as above ?.

Help is much appriciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM   users 
       LEFT JOIN users_approval b
          ON users.username = b.username AND
             b.approved_id = "3B888F52-50BC-11E2-B08B-99E5B2CADDF7"
WHERE  users.role_type = "student" AND
       b.approved_id IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ffa1/6)

Comment: awesome ..! I got some IDEA on how joins work now :P. Thanks a LOT KJ

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    users.* 
FROM users as u
LEFT JOIN users_approval as ua ON  ua.id = u.id
WHERE u.role_type = "student" AND ua.approved_id IS NULL
```

Assuming you have user_id as foreign key in the second table it can be used to join instead of using username to join table